# EF Error Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20004]

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-8.0

In .NET 8 I have `DbContext` that works in API controller. It throws an error if I try to access the `DbContext` in a service. How can I use this context outside my controller?

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20004]
> An error occurred using the connection to database 'SomeContext' on server '(localdb)\mssqllocaldb'.

Connection string:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "SomeContext": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=SomeContext;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
}
```

In `program.cs`:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<SomeContext>(options =>
options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("SomeContext") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'SomeContext' not found.")));
```

The service that is throwing this error:

```
private readonly SomeContext_context;

public CqcService(SomeContext context)
{
    _context = context;
}

public async Task<Provider?> GetProvider(string id)
{
    var dbProvider = await _context.Provider.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.ProviderId == id);

    return dbProvider;
}
```

Comment: Naming conventions suggest that you method name `GetProvider` should end with `Async` to indicate it is a method you should `await` on.

Answer (score 0):

I had to await my method when I called it like so:

```
 var providers = await _SomeService.GetProviders("1");
```